# Изменение позиции Grid через margin с помощью PreviewMouseWheel

Tags: c#, wpf

Прошу помочь реализовать прокрутку колесиком мышки. В форме две кнопки - влево и вправо - при нажатии на одну из них меняется положение `Grid` через `Margin`, я пыталась сделать так же через колесо мышки, но результатов нет(
Код `Grid` элемента

```
<Grid Name="realm1_newsBlock"
      Margin="0,0,-722,0" 
      PreviewMouseWheel="realm1_newsBlock_PreviewMouseWheel">
</Grid>
```

обработчик нажатия кнопки:

```
private void rrr_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{ 
    string getRealm = (tabRealms.SelectedItem as TabItem).Name; 
    string getNumb = (getRealm + "_newsBlock"); 
    object item = tabRealms.FindName(getNumb);
    if (item is Grid) 
    { 
        Grid getBlockName = (Grid)item;
        Thickness margin = getBlockName.Margin;
        if (margin.Left >= -722)
        { 
            margin.Left -= 200;
            getBlockName.BeginAnimation(FrameworkElement.MarginProperty, new ThicknessAnimation(margin, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0.25)));
        } 
    }  
}
```

Не знаю, что писать в методе  `realm1_newsBlock_PreviewMouseWheel`

Comment: Прикрепите в вопрос код обработчиков кнопок

Comment: я столько вариантов перепробовала, а после удалила эту кашу. мне нужно, чтобы колесико мышки изменяло margin при прокрутке

Comment: а зачем вам двигать `Grid`? Опишите вашу задачу

Comment: Грид выходит за рамки формы, в форме две кнопки - влево и вправо - при нажатии одной из них грид двигается в ту или иную сторону по Margin.Left...  Так же я хочу делать это с помощью колеса мышки, так же как и с нажатием на кнопку

Comment: ну с помощью кнопок у вас же работает? приведите код обработчиков нажатий на кнопку, а потом и переделаем под колесико

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вынесите в отдельные методы те части кода которые отвечают за сдвиг сетки.
Назовите их `leftShift(Grid grid)` и `rightShift(Grid grid)`.

теперь смотрим обработчик события `PreviewMouseWheel`:

в аргументах `MouseWheelEventArgs` есть свойство `Delta`:

если `Delta < 0`, то было вращение на себя(колесико вниз)

если `Delta > 0`, то вперед

```
private void realm1_newsBlock_PreviewMouseWheel(object sender, MouseWheelEventArgs e)
{
     if (e.Delta < 0)
         leftShift(/*сюда передаете ваш grid*/); //сдвиг влво
     else
         rightShift(/*сюда передаете ваш grid*/); //сдвиг вправо
}
```

вот собственно и все, главное определить в какую сторону было вращение.

Comment: ну поняла, что сделать с этим  leftShift(Grid grid); rightShift(Grid grid);?

Comment: а так же тут - /*сюда передаете ваш grid*/  - что нужно вставить?

Comment: Вынесите код который сдвигает grid в эти методы, а в параметрах передавайте собственно ваш grid(getBlockName)

Comment: `private void tabRealms_PreviewMouseWheel(object sender, MouseWheelEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Delta < 0)
                leftShift(grid(getBlockName));
            else
                rightShift(grid(getBlockName));
        }`   вы имели ввиду вот так?

Comment: ` private void rightShift(Grid grid)
       { string getRealm = (tabRealms.SelectedItem as TabItem).Name; string getNumb = (getRealm + "_newsBlock");
object item = tabRealms.FindName(getNumb);
 if (item is Grid)
 {
 Grid getBlockName = (Grid)item;
Thickness margin = getBlockName.Margin;
 if (margin.Left >= -722)
{
 margin.Left -= 200;
                  getBlockName.BeginAnimation(FrameworkElement.MarginProperty, new ThicknessAnimation(margin, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0.25)));
}
 }
 }`   вот метод на перемещение вправо... только у меня все равно ругается на все, что только можно(

Comment: Вопрос решен, я скопировала весь код левой части и правой и вставила в метод, который будет отвечать за передвижение.. осталось только исправить небольшие тормоза при прокрутке вышкой

Comment: А есть какие нибудь методы, позволяющие задать плавность при прокрутке?

Comment: TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0.25)), вот этот параметр влияет на время за которое произойдет анимация, хотите чтоб быстрее, сделайте например 0.1

Comment: Спасибо большое за помощь!

Comment: @Елизавета, пожалуйста!